# How to ignore whitespaces in elastic search

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-5

In Elasticsearch, I have a field called "address", in that field data is indexed as

```
"322 Wall       Tax    Road"
```

In between each words multiple spaces have been added. So while searching for "322 Wall Tax Road" does not returning data.

is there any way to ignore additional whitespaces without reindexing.
Thank you.

This is my current mapping

```
"mappings": {
"esiid": {
"properties": {
"address": {
  "type": "string",
  "index": "not_analyzed"
},
"city": {
  "type": "string"
},

"zip": {
  "type": "string"
}
}
}
```

Comment: Have you considered regular expressions? Split your string in words and use regex for multiple whitespaces between each word: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html

Answer (score -1):

How about to just simply replace the double whitespace with a single space?

```
$workedString = str_replace("  "," ",$yourString);
```